# Display feature length in legend in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.2

Using ArcMap 10.2, how can I show the total feature length instead of feature count in the legend?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.